# R Looping through list of follower to get ego network using twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to get network data on who follows who based on a closed list of twitter accounts who are followed by a given user. That is, given *User A*, I'd like to retrieve its friends list and then learn who of its friends follows each other.

The first issue I had was the rate limit set by the Twitter API, but seemed to solve it using the *Sys.sleep()* function. Although very slow, I used the function shown below and it worked fine the first time. However, I am trying to get the same info from other users' friends list and it keeps on giving me errors of the type:

- Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached
- Error HTTP 503
  And other errors. So far I've tried it three times in three different laptops and got a different error each time. Any idea why this may be happening?

Thanks a lot in advance!

```
friendsnet <- function(tuser) {
  require(twitteR)

  # if rate limit is hit, wait for 15 minutes
  limit <- getCurRateLimitInfo()[53,3]
  print(paste("Look up limit", limit))
  if (limit == 0) {
    print("sleeping for fifteen minutes")
    Sys.sleep(900)
  }

  # Find user
  tuser <- getUser(tuser)
  print(tuser$screenName)

  # Empty dataframe
  df <- NULL
  print("empty data frame")

  # Get names of friends
  f <- lookupUsers(tuser$getFriendIDs())
  f.id <- sapply(f, id)
  f.name <- sapply(f, screenName)
  f2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(f.id, f.name))
  print("list of friends")
  print(head(f2))

  for (i in f2$f.name) {

    # if rate limit is hit, wait for 15 minutes
    limit <- getCurRateLimitInfo()[53,3]
    print(paste("Look up limit", limit))
    if (limit == 0) {
      print("sleeping for fifteen minutes")
      Sys.sleep(900)
    }
    A <- getUser(i)
    friends.object <- lookupUsers(A$getFriendIDs())
    # Convert list into data frame
    friends.id <- sapply(friends.object,id)
    friends.name <- sapply(friends.object, screenName)
    friends <- as.data.frame(cbind(friends.id, friends.name))

    for (j in f2$f.name) {
      if (i != j) {
        if ((j %in% friends$friends.name) == TRUE) {
          print(paste(i, "follows", j))
          df <- rbind(df, data.frame(i, j))
        }
      }

    }

  }
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: The code seem to be correct. It sometimes work, although terribly slow. Probably has to do with the Internet connection

Comment: Same errors. It doesn' work for me.